# Actionscript - How to override getting pre-defined properties of classes?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, proxy, proxy-classes

I have a class which extends the Proxy class, and has a statically defined member variable called `num`:

```
public dynamic class TestProxy extends Proxy
{
 private var num:Number = 100;

 public function TestProxy()
 {
  super();
 }

 override flash_proxy function getProperty(name:*):*
 {
  trace("***** "+name);
 }
}
```

I want getProperty() to be called when I attempt access `num`. It works for any field which does not already exist, but not for fields that are predefined.

Is there some way to make this happen? Can I somehow dynamically get rid of `num`? Or something else?

Comment: When are you calling `num` because outside this class it will be undefined since it's private.

Answer (score 0):

If it's predefined why can't you use a getter/setter method and proxy access to private var that way?

```
private var _num:Number = 100;
//....
function get num () : Number { }
function set num (val : Number) : void { }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to avoid; I am trying to define model objects whose properties are looked up lazily + remotely upon getting them, as the data does not exist in the class upon instantiation. It is not just one object, it is potentially dozens; writing these getters/setters to do **exactly the same thing** for each property would be an awful hassle and seems really unclean.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to have `Proxy` access private pre-defined properties of a class. Either make it public if you want it accessed, or rename the variable and then respond to `num` calls:

```
public dynamic class TestProxy extends Proxy
{
    private var _num:Number = 100;

    public function TestProxy()
    {
        super();
    }

    override flash_proxy function getProperty(name:*):*
    {
        if (name == "num")
        {
            return _num;
        }
    }
}
```